# Displaying tooltip on mouse hover of a text

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip, richtextbox

I want to display a tooltip when the mouse hovers over a link in my custom rich edit control. Consider the following text:

> We all **sleep** at night .

In my case the word ***sleep*** is a link.

When the user moves the mouse under the link, in this case "sleep", I want to display a tooltip for the link.

The following came to my mind, but they are not working

1) Trapping OnMouseHover

```
if(this.Cursor == Cursors.Hand)
   tooltip.Show(textbox,"My tooltip");
else
   tooltip.Hide(textbox);
```

But this does not work out.

**UPDATE**

The links mentioned are **not** URLs, i.e these are custom links, so Regex won't be of much help here, it can be any text. The user can choose to create it a a link.

Though I have not tried `GetPosition` method, I dont think it would be that elegant in terms of design and maintenance.

Let me say I have the following line, in my richedit box

> We ***sleep*** at night. But the bats stay ***awake***. Cockroaches become ***active*** at night.

In the above sentence, I want three different tooltips, when the mouse hovers over them.

```
sleep -> Human beings
awake -> Nightwatchman here
active -> My day begins
```

I trapped `OnMouseMove` as follows:

**Working- with Messagebox**

```
OnMouseMove( )
{

   // check to see if the cursor is over a link
   // though this is not the correct approach, I am worried why does not a tooltip show up
   if(this.Cursor.current == Cursors.hand )
   {
     Messagebox.show("you are under a link");
   }
}
```

**Not Working - with Tooltip - Tooltip does not show up**

```
OnMouseMove( MouseventArgs e )
{

   if(cursor.current == cursors.hand )
   {
     tooltip.show(richeditbox,e.x,e.y,1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick .. tooltip.Active = true

Comment: Oh I didn't realize your issue was the tooltip itself... 
Anyway, use System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current to statically get the current mouse cursor, as in my last answer.

Answer (score 24):

Just add ToolTip tool from toolbox to the form and add this code in a mousemove event of any control you want to make the tooltip start on its mousemove

```
private void textBox3_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox3,"Tooltip text"); // you can change the first parameter (textbox3) on any control you wanna focus
    }
```

hope it helps

peace

Comment: it is enough to set set toolTip1.SetToolTip(textBox3,"Tooltip text"); only once, not every time the mousemove-event is raised.

Answer (score 17):

Well, take a look, this works, If you have problems please tell me:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1() { InitializeComponent(); }

        ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
        void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!timer1.Enabled)
            {
                string link = GetWord(richTextBox1.Text, richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location));
                //Checks whether the current word i a URL, change the regex to whatever you want, I found it on www.regexlib.com.
//you could also check if current word is bold, underlined etc. but I didn't dig into it.
                if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(link, @"^(http|https|ftp)\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(:[a-zA-Z0-9]*)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-\._\?\,\'/\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~])*$"))
                {
                    tip.ToolTipTitle = link;
                    Point p = richTextBox1.Location;
                    tip.Show(link, this, p.X + e.X,
                        p.Y + e.Y + 32, //You can change it (the 35) to the tooltip's height - controls the tooltips position.
                        1000);
                    timer1.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //The timer is to control the tooltip, it shouldn't redraw on each mouse move.
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        public static string GetWord(string input, int position) //Extracts the whole word the mouse is currently focused on.
        {
            char s = input[position];
            int sp1 = 0, sp2 = input.Length;
            for (int i = position; i > 0; i--)
            {
                char ch = input[i];
                if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
                {
                    sp1 = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = position; i < input.Length; i++)
            {
                char ch = input[i];
                if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n')
                {
                    sp2 = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return input.Substring(sp1, sp2 - sp1).Replace("\n", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't use *the control private tooltip*, but the *form one*. This example works well:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.toolTip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(this.components);

        MyRitchTextBox myRTB = new MyRitchTextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(myRTB);

        myRTB.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        myRTB.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(myRTB_MouseEnter);
        myRTB.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(myRTB_MouseLeave);
    }


    void myRTB_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyRitchTextBox rtb = (sender as MyRitchTextBox);
        if (rtb != null)
        {
            this.toolTip1.Show("Hello!!!", rtb);
        }
    }

    void myRTB_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyRitchTextBox rtb = (sender as MyRitchTextBox);
        if (rtb != null)
        {
            this.toolTip1.Hide(rtb);
        }
    }


    public class MyRitchTextBox : RichTextBox
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not elegant, but you might be able to use the RichTextBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition method to return to you the index of the character that the mouse is currently over, and then use that index to figure out if it's over a link, hotspot, or any other special area.  If it is, show your tooltip (and you'd probably want to pass the mouse coordinates into the tooltip's Show method, instead of just passing in the textbox, so that the tooltip can be positioned next to the link).

Example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition(VS.80).aspx

Comment: I did the following; just for testing in the MouseMove event of the richedit box.

if(Cursor.Current == Cursors.Hand)
     Messagebox.Show("My Tooltip);

But my tooltip is not getting displayed, once I replace the Messagebox with the tooltip.show() as below

if(Cursor.Current == Cursors.Hand)
     this.ttpLink.Show("Hover",txtBox,e.X,e.Y,1000);

Am I missing something ?

Comment: Jean, even I get the text how do I know the atring ia link,

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
ToolTip tip = new ToolTip();
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor a = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current;
    if (a == Cursors.Hand)
    {
        Point p = richTextBox1.Location;
        tip.Show(
            GetWord(richTextBox1.Text,
                richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location)),
            this,
            p.X + e.X,
            p.Y + e.Y + 32,
            1000);
    }
}
```

Use the GetWord function from my other answer to get the hovered word.
Use timer logic to disable reshow the tooltip as in prev. example.

In this example right above, the tool tip shows the hovered word by checking the mouse pointer.

If this answer is still not what you are looking fo, please specify the condition that characterizes the word you want to use tooltip on.
If you want it for bolded word, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I would also like to add something here that if you load desired form that contain tooltip controll before the program's run then tool tip control on that form will not work as described below...

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        objfrmmain = new Frm_Main();
        Showtop();//this is procedure in program.cs to load an other form, so if that contain's tool tip control then it will not work
        Application.Run(objfrmmain);


    }
```

so I solved this problem by puting following code in Fram_main_load event procedure like this

```
    private void Frm_Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Program.Showtop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RichTextBox control. You can simply define the ToolTip object and show the tool-tip as the text is selected by moving the mouse inside the RichTextBox control.

```
    ToolTip m_ttInput = new ToolTip(); // define as member variable

    private void rtbInput_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rtbInput.SelectedText.Length > 0) 
        {
            m_ttInput.Show(rtbInput.SelectedText.Length.ToString(), rtbInput, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of ease of use and understandability.

You can simply put a Tooltip anywhere on your form (from toolbox). You will then be given an options in the Properties of everything else in your form to determine what is displayed in that Tooltip (it reads something like "ToolTip on toolTip1"). Anytime you hover on an object, the text in that property will be displayed as a tooltip.

This **does not** cover custom on-the-fly tooltips like the original question is asking for. But I am leaving this here for others that do not need

Answer (score -1):

As there is nothing  in this question (but its age) that requires a solution in `Windows.Forms`, here is a way to do this in `WPF` in code-behind.

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("Background indicates packet repeat status:"));
tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
Run r = new Run("White");
r.Background = Brushes.White;
r.ToolTip = "This word has a White background";
tb.Inlines.Add(r);
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("\t= Identical Packet received at this time."));
tb.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
r = new Run("SkyBlue");
r.ToolTip = "This word has a SkyBlue background";
r.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue);
tb.Inlines.Add(r);
tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("\t= Original Packet received at this time."));

myControl.Content = tb;
```