# tooltip text property on user controls of system windows forms missing

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, tooltip

After using C# a while, I recognized that the user controls of system windows forms don't provide a tooltiptext property like I am knowing it from Visual Basic 6. 
I saw that the Form, TextBox, Label, ComboBox and PictureBox don't have such property.
Now I have the curious question:
How would I display a tooltip to the user on mousehover over a control like the above mentioned?

And Yes, I saw the "tooltip" control in the toolbox. It provides a baloon and I do not need a baloon.
It shows the tooltip for one item only once per user session and then never (known problem of the component) and why I would need an extra component, if this should be just a property of the corresponding control, for which I would like to provide a tooltip like TextBoxes, Labels etc.

And Yes, I saw the "Help Provider". I have usually never a help file assigned with my projects,
so I do not use the Help System. What I need is a simple Tooltiptext, not a "F1 component".
Now I am curious, how I would implement a Tooltiptext if the controls don't provide a option for it.
Can it be, that C# has no control tooltips? Even Delphi has! Or have I missed something somewhere?

**The solution:**

1. Delete all notifyicon controls from your project to ensure no unwanted info bubbles appearing
   in the system tray.
2. Drag and Drop the Tooltip Component in Toolbox on your form, but **ignore** all the baloon properties and the baloon timeout properties and baloon timer properties, just Drag and Drop
   the component without further action.
3. A weird new property field "tooltip on tooltip1" shows now up in all TextBoxes and Labels etc. on the form.
   Just handle this field as it would be your Tooltip property and don't setup anything else in code
   or on the designer. Build and compile. The tooltiptext will now show up as normal tooltip without
   baloon functionality.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: How do I add a ToolTip to a control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339524/c-how-do-i-add-a-tooltip-to-a-control)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you are using the ToolTip control incorrectly.

1- Drag it from the toolbox to your form.

At this point, each control on the form now gets a property "Tooltip" to set the appropriate text.

2- Set each control's new "ToolTip" property in the way you find most intuitive.