# Tooltip on Console Application - Desktop

Tags: c#, .net, tooltip, console-application, desktop

I thought about adding a fancy thing to a project by having a tooltip displaying some results. Didn't know it was that complicated.
I have been googling this for a while but didn't find something very clear.
I was wondering how can I create a simple tooltip on the desktop on a console application.
Like this picture

[image]

Sorry for the newbie question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused on what you're requesting here.

In your question, you state you want to create a tool-tip in a "console application". For console applications, you cannot create tool-tips because they are command-line interfaces.

Here are some resources if you want to create tool-tips in a [Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339524/c-how-do-i-add-a-tooltip-to-a-control) or [WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx) application.

Comment: Then that is the answer. I guess I will need to create a bordless GUI instead. Thank you