# How to make new event when hover on a text in RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, richtextbox, mousehover

I have a `RichTextBox` that contains a string, e.g: "Hello", and I want to create a new event when I hover the mouse over the word "Hello", or to simplify that, showing a message box when hover on the word "Hello". So how to achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off let's define a method that gets the word nearest to the cursor:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static string GetWordUnderCursor(RichTextBox control, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //check if there's any text entered
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(control.Text))
            return null;
        //get index of nearest character
        var index = control.GetCharIndexFromPosition(e.Location);
        //check if mouse is above a word (non-whitespace character)
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(control.Text[index]))
            return null;
        //find the start index of the word
        var start = index;
        while (start > 0 && !char.IsWhiteSpace(control.Text[start - 1]))
            start--;
        //find the end index of the word
        var end = index;
        while (end < control.Text.Length - 1 && !char.IsWhiteSpace(control.Text[end + 1]))
            end++;
        //get and return the whole word
        return control.Text.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
    }
}
```

In order to raise `MouseMove` event ONLY if the cursor is above `RichTextBox` and the nearest word is `"Hello"` you'll need to define your own control deriving from `RichTextBox` and override the `OnMouseMove` method, and use it in your form instead `RichTextBox`:

```
public class MyRichTextBox : RichTextBox
{
    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //get the word under the cursor
        var word = Helper.GetWordUnderCursor(this, e);
        if (string.Equals(word, "Hello"))
        {
            //let RichTextBox raise the event
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
        }
    }
}
```

However, in my opinion, it's better to let the `RichTextBox` raise the `MouseMove` event normally and take action only if conditions are met. In order to do that you only need to register `MouseMove` handler and check the conditions:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var control = sender as RichTextBox;
    //get the word under the cursor
    var word = Helper.GetWordUnderCursor(control, e);
    if (string.Equals(word, "Hello"))
    {
        //do your stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [Cursor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to achieve this. Some people tried to achieve similar things. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873175/displaying-tooltip-on-mouse-hover-of-a-text).

Answer (score -2):

Make sure you have an event **'richTextBox1_MouseHover'** wired to the hover of your Rich Text Box.

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to create that event when I hover on that specific string, not on the whole RichTextBox.