# I am trying to do multiline ToolTip. Linebreaking characters don`t work

Tags: c#, tooltip

I am trying to create multiline ToolTip.

```
myToolTip.ToolTipTitle="First line\nSecond line";
myToolTip.ToolTipTitle="First line\r\nSecond line";
myToolTip.ToolTipTitle="First line\nSecond line";
string s="First line\nSecond line";
s = s.Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine);
myToolTip.ToolTipTitle=s;
```

All the above code shows only oneline tooltip and always adds extra row below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN9gG.png)
I tried to insert in ToolTipTitle string line break characters such as "\r\n" "\n" or Environment.Newline, but it still does not work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The ToolTipTitle can't have multiple lines, but the caption can.

Try it this way:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine("First Line");
sb.AppendLine("Second Line");
myToolTip.SetToolTip(button1, sb.ToString());
```

or

```
myToolTip.Show(sb.ToString(), button1);
```

Comment: Thank you @LarsTech. I found the resolution and added my own answer with working example.

Comment: @Alexander Wasn't that pretty much my answer?

Comment: Yes, it much, but I provided full working example. Besides, I think using symbol "\n" to break string is the shortest way. I also experienced the problem with flickering, when user moves the mouse over the PictureBox. This was also resolved.

Comment: @Alexander Shorter isn't always better.  It's safer to use Environment.NewLine or the AppendLine in my example.  Your question didn't address the flicker issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the resolution that is partially based on [@Shimmy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75500/shimmy) answer on the question [Displaying tooltip on mouse hover of a text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873175/displaying-tooltip-on-mouse-hover-of-a-text).

I had to use toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, TextString) function. ToolTip Title can`t be multiline.

The Timer is needed to avoid flickering. When the user moves mouse over PictureBox the ToolTip shows multiline text.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip toolTip1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer ToolTipsTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ToolTipsTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(ToolTipsTimerEventProcessor);
        ToolTipsTimer.Interval = 300;
        ToolTipsTimer.Start();
        toolTip1.AutomaticDelay = 300;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private void ToolTipsTimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        ToolTipsTimer.Enabled = false;
    }

    string TextString = "First line\n Second line";
    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!ToolTipsTimer.Enabled)
        {
            toolTip1.SetToolTip(pictureBox1, TextString);
            ToolTipsTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you answer your own question with help of [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39534999/3110834) a good manner is upvoting the answer which you used to solve the problem :)

Answer (score -2):

There is not enough of your JavaScript code to troubleshoot your problem. If you were using a popup alert() then the "\n\n" would work; I do that all the time.

This is one workaround: Use the HTML5 title attribute and hard-code the line breaks. Like this: