# How to locate and get text from a tooltip?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate a tooltip within a div, and then extract the tooltip-text which is visible when I do mouse hover over the tooltip. 
Copying below the code snapshot from UI --

```
<div class="w-table w-table-hover ng-star-inserted">
    <table class="w-table  w-table-hover">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="w-table-border">
                <td class="w-table-row pl-3 w-table-width-60">
                    John Spiderman (123456)
                </td>
                <td class="w-table-row pl-2 w-table-width-25">
                    Open
                </td>
                <td class="w-table-row text-right px-2 w-table-width-15">
                    <!---->
                    <div class="w-table-row-text ng-star-inserted">
                        Unavailable
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle w-icon-question-circle" 
                           container="body"
                           placement="right"
                           id="tooltip-report-account-123456">
                        </i>
                    </div>
                    <!---->
                </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

I have tried to do the following to locate the element and then grab text out of it, however its not working as the text is only displayed on mouse hover

```
var tooltipElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("tooltip-report-account-" + accountNumber));
Assert.AreEqual(tooltipElement.Text.ToLower().Trim(), 'This account is unavailable');
```

unable to find the element

Comment: Why dont you store the account number in Context and retrieve from it. As far as I remember tooltip only work only mouse hover. Have you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/873175/displaying-tooltip-on-mouse-hover-of-a-text)

Comment: `locate a tooltip within a div` presumably the text **Unavailable** appears to be the tooltip but necessarily you don't _mouse hover over the tooltip_ and you need to update the question with the element on which you need to _Mouse Hover_

Answer (score 0):

I guess the string `This account is` is a prefix in javascript function, why not just compare with `Unavailable` which is text from the parent of that element ID.

```
var tooltipElement = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//i[@id='tooltip-report-account-" + accountNumber + "']/parent::div"));
Assert.AreEqual(tooltipElement.Text.ToLower().Trim(), 'unavailable');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform mousehover first by using action class and then try to locate element which displays tooltip

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
var element = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(<element xpath>)));
Actions action = new Actions(Driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Perform();   
//Waiting for the menu to be displayed    
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to find the element; then maybe locator used has some problem.
Try with below xpath for once:

```
var tooltipElement = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//*[contains(@id,'tooltip-report-account')]"));
```